# Better way to determine seconds since power on in microcontroller?

Tags: c, microcontroller

Short question: How to get seconds since reset in STM32L051T6 microcontroller?

My effort and detailed issue:

I am using an STM32L051T6 series microcontroller. I need to count seconds since power on. I am also using low power mode. So I wrote code to use wakeup timer interrupt functionality of internal RTC of microcontroller. I used 1 second interval wake up timer with external LSE clock of 32768 Hz. I observed the accumulated seconds since power on (SSPO) after 3 days and found that it is falling behind by 115 seconds compared to actual time elapsed. My guess for this drift is interrupt latency in executing wakeup timer interrupt. How can I remove drift of this 115 seconds? Or is there any other better method than using wakeup interrupt to count seconds since power on?

UPDATE:

I tried to use Systick with HAL_GetTick() function as seconds since power on. But even systick is also getting delayed over time.

Comment: Does the MCU have a RTC? Then on startup store the time of the RTC, and when you need to get the uptime you get the difference between the current RTC and the stored startup-time.

Comment: Yes RTC is there, but at startup it may not have time set. So can't use this method.

Comment: How are you comparing the counted and the real elapsed time? How is RTC clocked: by external quartz or internal RC oscillator?

Comment: At start I note the time on time.gov. I take the epoc of that and I use that epoch as reference after 3 days. RTC is clocked with External LSE clock of 32768 Hz.

Comment: This has very little to do with programming and a lot to do with choice of clock/oscillator. It is not meaningful to discuss this without mentioning the used hardware. Therefore this question is better suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The accuracy of your system is, at least, affected by temperature. Oscillator freq could drift. As @Lundin already wrote this question has little to do with programming.

Comment: @LPs Please read the question again.

Comment: Unless you are resetting the RTC within the interrupt handler, then the interrupt latency should not accumulate from one second to the next.  The next interrupt from the RTC will be 1 second after the previous interrupt even if you serviced that first interrupt up to 1 second late.  If you're interrupt latency is more than a second then you will miss interrupts and drop seconds.  But it seems more likely that the drift you are experiencing is due to inaccuracy of the clock feeding the RTC rather than interrupt latency.

Comment: When your interrupts are 1 second apart, interrupt latency cannot be an issue, unless of course you unnecessarily keep interrupts disabled for too long for other work, but I'm assuming you know better than that :)  I would check the accuracy of your 32768 Hz clock source.  Have you verified with a frequency counter?  (Depending on your external oscillator type, it may require fine tuning adjustments to bring it dead on the nominal frequency.)  As others already mentioned, significant temperature variations over time may also affect the accuracy of your clock frequency.

Comment: You say you get a drift of 115 seconds in 3 days. Does the RTC clock have same drift or is it more accurate? I understand that it can be reset by user, but if it is accurate, you could at least try to use it.

Comment: What low-power mode do you use? Sleep/Standby/Stop ? If you are stopping only core, you can use any general-purpose timer.
Also, your MCU have additional low-power timer (see LPTIM in reference manual), which can be used in various sleep modes.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes RTC time is accurate over time. Only seconds counted using wakeup interrupt of RTC are getting delayed.

Comment: @AlexeyEsaulenko I am using stop mode of low power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure time with accuracy over a longer period, an RTC is the way to go. As you mentioned that you have an RTC, you can use the method below.

At startup, load the RTC with zero.

Then you can read the seconds elapsed when required without the errors above.

Edit: As per comment, the RTC can be changed by user. In that case,

If you can modify the RTC write function called by the user, then when the user calls the RTC write function, you update a global variable `VarA = time set by user`.  The elapsed time will be `Time read by RTC - VarA`.

Comment: The time in RTC can be changed by user. So simply reading time from RTC will not work even if I set RTC 0 initially.

Comment: I don't know what is channel in RTC. It's internal RTC of microcontroller. Can't see anything regarding channel of RTC in datasheet.

Comment: There is nothing magical about a RTC. Like any hardware peripheral in your MCU, it inherits its clock from somewhere. So its usefulness depends on the clock source. If the clock source is inaccurate, the RTC will drift.

Comment: @Lundin I am not saying that RTC is drifting. I am saying that seconds counted with wakeup timer functionality of RTC are drifiting and my guess for this drift is interrupt latency.

Comment: @DarshanPrajapati Interrupt latency would not affect a correctly written program. If you trigger an interrupt that fires up lets say every second and increases a counter, then you could have an interrupt latency of up to one second without losing any accuracy.

Comment: @Lundin He is going to sleep and then waking from sleep every second. I guess this is causing the errors.

Comment: If you only get a drift of 115 seconds in 3 days, I very much doubt the problem is related to software.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Global variable method is incorrect as difference between current time and global variable does not give exact SSPO.

Answer (score 0):

If the RTC is accurate, you should use the RTC by storing its value at boot time and later comparing to that saved value. But you said that the RTC can be reset by user so I can see two ways to cope with it:

- if you have enough control on the system, replace the command or IHM that a user can use to reset the clock with a wrapper that inform you module and allows to read the RTC before and after it has been reset
- if you have not enough control or cannot wrap the user's reset (because it uses a direct system call, etc.) use a timer to control the RTC value on every second

But you should define a threshold on the delta on RTC clock. If it is *small*, it is likely to be an adjustment because unless your system uses an atomic clock, even RTC can derive over time. In that case I would not care because you can hardly know whether it derived since last reboot or not. If you want a more clever algorythm, you can make the threshold dependant on the current time since last reboot: the longer the system is up, the higher the probability it has derived since then.

On the opposite, a *large* delta is likely to be a correction because RTC was blatantly erroneous, the saving battery is out of use, or what else. In that case you should compute the new *start RTC time* that gives same duration with the new RTC value.

As a rule of thumb, I would use a threshold of about 1 or 2 seconds per uptime day without RTC clock adjustement ([ref](http://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/ppm.html)) - meaning I would also store the time of last RTC adjustement, initially boot time.